# How to set the frame of webview on orientation change in iOS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a webview which I have added to xib which is in portrait mode. I have set the frame of webview in xib as (0,54,768,905). When I run my app in portrait mode it is displaying the webview in proper frame but when I rotate from portrait to landscape my webview frame is not getting set properly.

In the will rotate interface orientation method I have set the frame of webview but no change is getting reflected. When I rotate from portrait to landscape the frame of webview starts from y position = 0 instead of 54.

This is my code:

```
  -(void)viewDidLoad
{  

        //Landscape
        viewstatus =@"landscape";


        if (webview)
        {
            [webview removeFromSuperview];
        }
        self.webview.frame =CGRectMake(0, self.view.origin.y+54, 1024, 680);
        [self.view addSubview:webview];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:dataObject];
        NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        [webview loadRequest:requestObj];
        NSString *insertRule1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"addCSSRule('html', 'padding: 0px; height: %fpx; -webkit-column-gap: 0px; -webkit-column-width: %fpx;')", 680.0f, 1024.0f];
        [webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:insertRule1];

        pagecontrol.frame =CGRectMake(300, 710, 150, 36);

    }else{

        //Portrait


        if (webview)
        {
            [webview removeFromSuperview];
        }
        self.webview.frame =CGRectMake(0, self.view.origin.y+54, 768, 905);
        [self.view addSubview:webview];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:dataObject];
        NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        [webview loadRequest:requestObj];


        NSString *insertRule1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"addCSSRule('html', 'padding: 0px; height: %fpx; -webkit-column-gap: 0px; -webkit-column-width: %fpx;')", 905.0f, 768.0f];
        [webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:insertRule1];
        pagecontrol.frame =CGRectMake(208, 959, 358, 36);

    }

    UITapGestureRecognizer* doubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action: @selector(handleDoubleTap:)];
    doubleTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 2 ;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap] ;
    UIScrollView* sv = nil;
    for(UIView* v in self.webview.subviews){
        if([v isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class] ]){
            sv = (UIScrollView*) v;
            [sv setZoomScale:9.0f animated:YES];
            //sv.scrollEnabled=YES;
            sv.bounces = NO;
        }
    }


    [pagecontrol setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];
    [pagecontrol addTarget:self action:@selector(changePage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [self.view addSubview:pagecontrol];
    webview.scrollView.delegate=self;
    webview.scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator=NO;
    webview.scrollView.bounces = NO;
    webview.scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
    pinchdetect=NO;
    pinchRecognizer = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(pinchDetected:)];
    [self.webview addGestureRecognizer:pinchRecognizer];

   }    

}




- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{

    if(toInterfaceOrientation == 1 || toInterfaceOrientation == 2)
    {
        viewstatus =@"portrait";



        [self.view bringSubviewToFront:pagecontrol];
            if (webview)
        {
            [webview removeFromSuperview];
        }
        self.webview.frame =CGRectMake(0, self.view.origin.y+54, 768, 905);
        [self.view addSubview:webview];
        NSString *insertRule1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"addCSSRule('html', 'padding: 0px; height: %fpx; -webkit-column-gap: 0px; -webkit-column-width: %fpx;')", 905.0f, 768.0f];
        [webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:insertRule1];
           //     webview.frame =CGRectMake(0, 54, 768, 905);
        pagecontrol.frame =CGRectMake(230, 959, 600, 36);


    }
    if(toInterfaceOrientation == 3 || toInterfaceOrientation == 4)
    {
        viewstatus =@"landscape";
        if (webview)
        {
            [webview removeFromSuperview];
        }
        self.webview.frame =CGRectMake(0, self.view.origin.y+54, 1024, 680);
        [self.view addSubview:webview];
        [self.view bringSubviewToFront:pagecontrol];
        NSString *insertRule1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"addCSSRule('html', 'padding: 0px; height: %fpx; -webkit-column-gap: 0px; -webkit-column-width: %fpx;')", 680.0f, 1024.0f];
        [webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:insertRule1];

        pagecontrol.frame =CGRectMake(300, 710, 150, 36);


    }
    [webview reload];

}
```

Comment: Why not try setting the AutoresizingMask to the webview ..[webView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | [UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight ];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using auto layout, and IB, when you drop your webview onto the view, use pinning.  Pin the top,leading,trailing and bottom to the view.  It will stick to it no matter what orientation you are using.  I did this a couple times and it works great.

Answer (score 0):

First set `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` to `YES` with bellow method

```
- (BOOL) shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation) orientation 
{
    return YES;
}
```

and then Add this bellow method

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
    if(fromInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait){
        [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"rotate(0)"];
    }
    else{
        [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"rotate(1)"];
    }
}
```